# Implementing async version of a sync method: How to return Task<int> which is constant 1?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a sync method, now I would like to implement its async version. Fortunately the underlying call already have an async version (`dbSet.SaveChangesAsync()`), however in my algorithm there is an if branch returning with constant literal 1.

I do not know how to implement this part in the async version?

Sync version:

```
    public virtual int Add(T entity)
    {
        SetLogContext(entity, _logctx);
        dbSet.Add(entity);

        if (isAutonomous)
        {
            return ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Async version:

```
    public virtual Task<int> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        SetLogContext(entity, _logctx);
        dbSet.Add(entity);

        if (isAutonomous)
        {
            return ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return ??? // What to write here?
    }
```

Comment: `return Task.FromResult(1);`

Comment: Doomer: This seems to be an answer, why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use

```
return Task.FromResult(1);
```

Comment: and the documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You have two possibilities how to achieve your needs: one is to use the `async` keyword:

```
public virtual async Task<int> AddAsync<T>(T entity)
{
    SetLogContext(entity, _logctx);
    dbSet.Add(entity);

    if (isAutonomous)
    {
        return await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The other is to use `Task.FromResult(1)` at the point where you want to return the number.

Comment: As I read the first one (async/await) is kinda anti-pattern this case... it creates one more extra state machine unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that you've created an "Async" method that isn't actually `async`. This could be pretty misleading for the next guy using it.

As @xxMUROxx already mentioned, an "Async" method should be prefixed with the `async` keyword.

```
    public virtual async Task<int> AddAsync<T>(T entity)
    {
        SetLogContext(entity, _logctx);
        dbSet.Add(entity);

        if (isAutonomous)
        {
            return await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

The whole point of using the `async` `await` pattern is to [change the way the program flows through methods](http://dylanwilson.net/what-do-the-async-and-await-keywords-actually-do/). When the `await` keyword is hit, the method returns to the caller and *usually* flows all the way back to the original caller. Typically that'll be an `async void` event handler like a button click.

When this happens, it allows the calling thread to continue executing while it's waiting for a long running operation to complete. After the long running operation completes the code will create a continuation and continue executing any other code that depends on the result returned.

By omitting the `async` keyword from the method, you've effectively made the call synchronous again. Defeating the purpose of calling `SaveChangesAsync` in the first place.

Comment: Surely the calling code can `await` the task returned by a method regardless of whether or not that method uses async/await itself?

Comment: It's all spelled out in the documentation. > "The `await` keyword can only be used in a method marked with `async`" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh156528.aspx

Comment: But that's not *at all* the same as the main claim in your answer, that a method which returns a Task but doesn't use async/await can't be called asynchronously.

Comment: True, you could run the Task returned from the method asynchronously regardless of the `async` keyword because it delegates to another `async` method. I guess I just got caught up in the semantics of the method naming. My apologies.

Comment: @craftworkgames I realize this is old, but the naming conventions suggest that a developer append `Async` to any method that returns a `Task`, rather than hinging on the idea that the method actually performs some internal `async` task. I find the naming convention silly, personally. It smells of hungarian notation, and we have chosen to omit it internally. I can't wait for Microsoft to abandon it.